# Loop validando dias da semana em PHP

Tags: php

Tenho o seguinte período:

```
15/10/2017 a 14/11/2017
```

(com opção selecionada de segunda, terça, quarta, quinta e sexta - sábado e domingo ficam inativos)

Preciso, através do PHP, montar um loop para eu liste todas as datas disponíveis com base nesse período, e com base também os dias da semana que foram selecionados.

Neste caso, o resultado seria:

```
16/10/2017
17/10/2017
18/10/2017
19/10/2017
20/10/2017
21/22 são sábado e domingo, por isso não listariam
23/10/2017
24/10/2017
25/10/2017
```

De que forma eu poderia fazer isto?

Pra facilitar, elaborei da seguinte forma:

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
    if(isset($_POST['inicio']) && isset($_POST['fim'])){        
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($_POST);
        echo "</pre>";
    }
?>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input type="date" id="inicio" name="inicio"><br>
    <input type="date" id="fim" name="fim"><br><br>

    <input type="checkbox" id="diasemana[]" name="diasemana[]" value="segunda">Segunda<br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="diasemana[]" name="diasemana[]" value="terca">Terça<br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="diasemana[]" name="diasemana[]" value="quarta">Quarta<br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="diasemana[]" name="diasemana[]" value="quinta">Quinta<br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="diasemana[]" name="diasemana[]" value="sexta">Sexta<br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="diasemana[]" name="diasemana[]" value="sabado">Sábado<br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="diasemana[]" name="diasemana[]" value="domingo">Domingo<br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Montar Rotina">
</form>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

Sugiro construir as checkboxes já com os valores de datas que pretende. Isso facilita bastante na interpretação do lado do PHP.

Para isso pode construir um array com os dias da semana em texto que começam no Domingo para corresponder com o dia da semana em PHP:

```
$diasTexto = Array("Domingo", "Segunda", "Terça", "Quarta", "Quinta", "Sexta", "Sábado");
```

Depois para outro array guarda a data correspondente andando dia a dia para a frente com base na classe [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.datetime.php) e nas funções [`add`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/datetime.add.php), [`format`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/datetime.format.php):

```
$data = new DateTime(); //construir com a data corrente

for ($i = 0; $i < 7; ++$i){
    $diaSemana = intval($data->format("w")); //obter o dia da semana
    $dias[$diaSemana] = $data->format("d-m-Y"); //guardar no array a data correspondente
    $data->add(new DateInterval('P1D')); //avançar 1 dia
}
```

A seguir basta mostrar as etiquetas `<input>` com base nestes dois arrays:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 7; ++$i){
    ?>
    <input type="checkbox" id="diasemana[]" name="diasemana[]" value="<?=$dias[$i]?>"><?=$diasTexto[$i]?><br>
    <?php
}
```

Com isto o html gerado terá o seguinte aspeto (considerando o dia de hoje de 15-10-2017):

```
<input type="checkbox" id="diasemana[]" name="diasemana[]" value="15-10-2017">Domingo<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="diasemana[]" name="diasemana[]" value="16-10-2017">Segunda<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="diasemana[]" name="diasemana[]" value="17-10-2017">Terça<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="diasemana[]" name="diasemana[]" value="18-10-2017">Quarta<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="diasemana[]" name="diasemana[]" value="19-10-2017">Quinta<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="diasemana[]" name="diasemana[]" value="20-10-2017">Sexta<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="diasemana[]" name="diasemana[]" value="21-10-2017">Sábado<br>
```

Agora quando o formulário for enviado, apenas leva as datas que pretende, sendo simples de tratar no PHP.

[Exemplo a funcionar no Ideone](https://ideone.com/29wBg1)